# Sequence counter with persistence

Tags: java, google-app-engine

In one of my object I needed a sequence I would use to increment an `Id` field just like we often do with classical databases. As I have not found a suitable solution, I wrote one. This solution uses objectify.

The first approach I came with was to have a class with a static `AtomicInteger` field like this:

```
public class MySequence {
  static AtomicInteger sequence = new AtomicInteger(0);
}
```

I would then just call it each time I need it.

**Problem:**

Every time the server is restarted, the sequence is too. So we need to persist the last value.

Second approach:

Persist the last value with objectify:

```
 public class MySequence {
        private static AtomicInteger sequence = new AtomicInteger(0);

        private static List<PersistSequence> l = null;


private static PersistSequence newPs = null;
    /**
     * @param user_id the id of the user we want to get the last value of the sequence
     * @return last value of PersistSequence
     */
    public static int getNextValue( String user_id){
        if( sequence.get() == 0){//first time we run it or it has been restarted
            l = ofy().load().type( PersistSequence.class).filter("user_id", user_id).limit(1).list();//grabs PersistSequence object bounded to user_id
            if( l != null){
                int dataStoreSeq = -1;
                if ( l.size() > 0) dataStoreSeq = l.get(0).getLastId();
                if ( dataStoreSeq > sequence.get()) sequence.set( dataStoreSeq);
                persistCounter( user_id, sequence.incrementAndGet());
                return sequence.get();
            }else{
                persistCounter( user_id, sequence.incrementAndGet());
                return sequence.get();
            }   
        }else{
            persistCounter( user_id, sequence.incrementAndGet());
            return sequence.get();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param user_id the id of the user
     * @param lastId last used Id
     */
    private static void persistCounter( String user_id, int lastId){
        //we only want one PersistSequence object per user so we delete the previous one before saving the new PersistSequence object
        List<Key<PersistSequence>> keys = ofy().load().type(PersistSequence.class).filter("user_id", user_id).keys().list();
        ofy().delete().keys(keys).now();
        //save the new one
        newPs = new PersistSequence();
        newPs.setLastId(lastId);
        newPs.setUserId(user_id);
        ofy().save().entities( newPs).now();
        } 
    }
```

I am happy with this code as it works well. However, I wonder if it still will rock if there is a high volume of users calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Shouldn't get id twice

I'm concerned with this code:

> ```
>         persistCounter( user_id, sequence.incrementAndGet());
>         return sequence.get();
> ```

After you atomically increment and get the counter, you call `sequence.get()` again.  That seems wrong because what happens if some other thread incremented the counter in the meantime?  I think your code should be:

```
        int newId = sequence.incrementAndGet();
        persistCounter(user_id, newId);
        return newId;
```

### Repeated code

Also, I noticed that the same block of code (the one above) appears three times in a row:

> ```
>     public static int getNextValue( String user_id){
>         if( sequence.get() == 0){//first time we run it or it has been restarted
>             l = ofy().load().type(PersistSequence.class).
>                     filter("user_id", user_id).limit(1).list();
>             if( l != null){
>                 int dataStoreSeq = -1;
>                 if ( l.size() > 0) dataStoreSeq = l.get(0).getLastId();
>                 if ( dataStoreSeq > sequence.get()) sequence.set( dataStoreSeq);
>                 persistCounter( user_id, sequence.incrementAndGet());
>                 return sequence.get();
>             }else{
>                 persistCounter( user_id, sequence.incrementAndGet());
>                 return sequence.get();
>             }   
>         }else{
>             persistCounter( user_id, sequence.incrementAndGet());
>             return sequence.get();
>         }
>     }
> ```

Since that code happens for every case, you can simplify your function by extracting that common code and placing it right before the function returns:

```
    public static int getNextValue( String user_id){
        if( sequence.get() == 0){//first time we run it or it has been restarted
            l = ofy().load().type(PersistSequence.class).
                    filter("user_id", user_id).limit(1).list();
            if( l != null){
                int dataStoreSeq = -1;
                if ( l.size() > 0) dataStoreSeq = l.get(0).getLastId();
                if ( dataStoreSeq > sequence.get()) sequence.set( dataStoreSeq);
            }
        }
        int newId = sequence.incrementAndGet();
        persistCounter(user_id, newId);
        return newId;
    }
```

### Concurrency issues in persistCounter()

It's possible that `persistCounter()` will get called with out of order `lastId` arguments.  For example, it's possible that you might get called with `lastId` of `5` and then later get called with a `lastId` of 4.  So I think before you save the new counter, you should compare it with the old one to make sure that are actually saving a newer counter.

Also, there may be a concurrency problem with this function.  What happens if one thread tries to save 4 and another tries to save 5 at the same time?  Could it possibly end up saving 4 instead of 5?

Comment: You right with the code getNextValue method. I will correct it accordingly.

Comment: Also persisCounter() is private and it should only be called when the value of lastId has been retrieved.
Please, see the code above. For concurrency issue I have added a call to ReentrantLock.